# What database to use for statistic / report data?

Tags: database, nosql

My application is a kind of POS system.
The problem is with reports. Sales per product, per table, per staff,categories. Having 1 year date range reports are very slow because they have to sum lots of rows etc. So i am wondering if a no-sql database could help ,like having summaries per day or something.. But maybe its not easy because there could be for each item * products * categories * staff etc query. SO what could i do ?

Comment: Take a look at [apache hadoop stack](https://hadoop.apache.org/), specifically at [map-reduce](https://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/)

Answer (score 5):

If you're comfortable with relational databases, I'd recommend sticking with them, and using daily aggregate tables for the reports you commonly use.

For example, if like to do sales reports grouped by product numbers, figure out what stats you're looking for (ie. quantity sold) and aggregate your raw data into day sized "buckets" by product number.

```
+-----------+------------+------------+-------+-------+
| salesdate | productNum | totalSales | stat2 | stat3 |
+-----------+------------+------------+-------+-------+
```

If you do day-sized buckets at the end of every day, you will only have 30 buckets per month for your report, or 365 buckets per year.  Much faster to summarize.  I've done this with network performance metrics when building out dashboards (hour-sized buckets), and it greatly reduces query time.  You can always dig into the raw data if need be, but for the average user who wants to see something at a glance, the aggregated buckets are enough.

You may also consider putting the summary tables in a separate database.

Just keep in mind, if one of your stats in an average, the average of a series of averages is not the average for the overall range.

Comment: This is exactly what we do for our users - a daily materialized view that they avoids the overhead of each user having to calculate the output.

Comment: i thought of this solution but queries are more complex. For example for a productNum how could i know how many are sold by seller with id X? per day ?I would need a column for each seller/staff. And each productnum may be canceled and i need a cancelation reason for example per day

Comment: Possibly a table grouped by seller, productNum, and salesDate.  Possibly another table aggregating just cancellations.  If there's multiple sellers in this system, "seller" and "salesDate" may be part of every aggregate table.  It's a balancing act choosing the right columns for aggregate table.  List out your common reports, the filters you use to build them, and the statistics they display.  Those filters and stats will be clues into how to build your aggregate tables.